# c# data table query not exist joins

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am bit confused with C# LINQ queries. I have a table with values as shown below

```
DataTable tableold = new DataTable();
tableold.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
tableold.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
tableold.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
tableold.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

// Here we add five DataRows.
tableold.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
```

Now I have another table

```
DataTable tableNew = new DataTable();
tableNew.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));

// Here we add five DataRows.
tableNew.Rows.Add(25);
tableNew.Rows.Add(50);
tableNew.Rows.Add(10);
```

I need to keep values in tableold (base table) which are not there in tableNew(new table).

So i need the updated data table (tableold) to look like this :

```
21, "Combivent", "Janet", "10:20:00"
100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", "10:20:00"
```

how to write such query in c# or LinQ

Please help! thanks

Comment: I dont follow how adding 3 rows in code = 5 rows, and how you expect 2 lines of output..  however, what did you actually try? Im guessing you want to select the tiesm from the newest table, and using the "numbers" you've picked select the corresponding lines from old..

Comment: i want to do not exist join and remove those lines which are same in both the tables and i need a final updated table

Comment: Well it really doesnt sound like you tried yet.. show what you tried and how did it not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var compare= tableold.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("Dosage"))
         .Except(tableNew.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("Dosage")));
 DataTable tblResult= (from row in tableold.AsEnumerable()
                                join id in compare
                                on row.Field<int>("Dosage") equals id
                                select row).CopyToDataTable();
```