# c# datatable filter using a string value

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to achieve another requirement where in i have data in datatable as shown below

```
DataTable tableold = new DataTable();
tableold.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(string));
tableold.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
tableold.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
tableold.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

// Here we add five DataRows.
tableold.Rows.Add(#25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(#50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(#10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(#21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
tableold.Rows.Add(#100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
```

Now i have a string array as show below

```
string[] values; (which contains {#25, #50, #10} values)
```

I need to remove values in tableold (base table) which are present in string array. (i know i am asking this very awkward, but im new to this)

So i need the updated data table (tableold) to look like this :

```
21, "Combivent", "Janet", "10:20:00"
100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", "10:20:00"
```

how to write such query in c# or LinQ

Please help! thanks

Comment: what is the difference between this and your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160642/c-sharp-data-table-query-not-exist-joins)?....

Comment: If you really want to **remove** records from the `DataTable`, this definitely is not a LINQ task. Search the `DataTable` documentation for the respective methods (how to find a row with a given criteria, how to delete a row etc.)

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ:

```
var newRows = tableold.AsEnumerable().Where(r => !values.Contains(r.Field<string>("Dosage")));
if(newRows.Any())
    tableold = newRows.CopyToDataTable();
else
    tableold = tableold.Clone(); // empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit unclear, I understand from output you want to exclude some `ids`. You could do something like this using `Linq`

```
// list of Ids to exclude
var ids = new List<int>() {25, 50, 10};

// filter table.    
var newTable = tableold.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x=> !ids.Contains(x.Field<int>("Dosage")))
        .CopyToDataTable();
```

Check this [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/03B2kL)